# How to trigger a function onChange of a value in Google Appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I recorded a macro on googlesheet, then i set up a trigger for it to run when ever there is a change.
The problem is that it runs whenever there is a change in any cell that when i want to type it jumps out of my current page.

I need the macro to run only when a particular cell changes(note CHANGE not EDIT cos the trigger cell changes by a counta formular

Below is an example of what i want to achieve

if checkerb1 changes, run macros if not , do nothing

Comment: You can use the `onChange` installable trigger. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change

Comment: You can use `if`. is there a problem?

Comment: @TheMaster 
I do not know how to write the code